how to remove header on data table

I have a problem how to remove "Data Export" cell that i export from data table.
this is my data table configuration :
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'Download Excel',
            title: 'Data export'
        }
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columns": [
        { "width": "20%" },
        { "width": "20%" },
        { "width": "20%" },
        { "width": "10%" },
        { "width": "15%" },
        { "width": "15%" }
    ]
});


use : colnames = NULL

where should i put that code?

Maybe just use     title: ''

See buttons.exportInfo() set title: null in buttons options

Could you provide a working example? There are a few options one can use to what you ask
